# Default binding to UserControl for custom DP

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, binding, user-controls

I have a custom DP that runs or stops an animation.  I want this to default to start and stop based on the `UserControl` visiblity (the DP is of type `Visibility` which makes this easier)

Can I do this in XAML, if so how (in such a way that a user can override this if they want)? If not how do I do it in code?

In straight up XAML i'll want something like this... im just not sure how it applies to defaults / styles etc

```
Animility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=Visibility}"
```

**Edit**

Would this work when set on the controls style?

```
<Setter Property="Animility" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=Visibility}"/>
```

Comment: Setting the binding in the UserControl's [default style](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1233888/1136211) should work. Didn't you try it? It would have to be Silverlight 5 for the binding in a property setter.

Comment: I propose a solution here or you do not play with the visibility but with another property: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17746202/1425718

Comment: Are you trying to create a custom control or are you creating a user control? These are two completely different things. Can you please share more of your code